# Possible values for type option for generating a class

Tags: angular-cli

Need help on the --type parameter of  **ng generate class**. When I ran the help for generate class command **ng g cl --help**  it shows the following

```
ng generate cl [name] <options...>
--dry-run Run through without making any changes.
  aliases:  -d -dryRun
--force Forces overwriting of files.
  aliases:  -f -force
--app Specifies app name to use.
  aliases:  -a -app
--collection Schematics collection to use.
  aliases:  -c -collection
--lint-fix Use lint to fix files after generation.
  aliases:  -lf -lintFix
--spec (boolean) Specifies if a spec file is generated.
--type (string) Specifies the type of class.
```

Does anyone know what are the values we can give for **--type** `option` and `their significance`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type option doesn't have any preset options, or list of values that are the only valid options. It's simply a string that you pass that will be appended to the end of the file that gets created.

For example, if you run this CLI command:

```
ng g cl person --type=base
```

This is the output in the console:

```
create src/app/person.base.ts (24 bytes)
```

BTW, I am on Angular CLI: 1.7.3.

Here is the output in the file:

```
export class Person {
}
```

If you run the same command without passing a type string, this is what you get:

```
create src/app/person.ts (24 bytes)
```

Here is the output in the file:

```
export class Person {
}
```

Exactly the same.

So, as you can see, the type option only effects the name of the file being created. I'm not sure I see the value in this option, because you can use `person.base` for the name option while running the command.

There is no documentation on the option in the CLI wiki, which leads me to believe it may go away in a future version.

Comment: Do you happen to know if we could use --type to select a different template for class generation, maybe defined at the root of the project ?